# PTVISIBLE always returns true when relevant point obscured by another window

Tags: windows

I am trying to ascertain whether the mouse cursor is over a specific window and whether there are any other windows obscuring that window at that specific point. The relevant point is obtained in screen coordinates by way of a mouse hook. I then use the `ptVisible` function to determine this. My code is:

```
DC := GetDC(wnd);
try
  Result := PtVisible(DC, pt.X, pt.Y);
finally
  ReleaseDC(wnd, DC);
end;
```

This always returns false even when there is nothing obscuring the window represented by the `wnd` handle.

I found very little on the web as to proper use of `ptVisible`. Can anyone advise if I am using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using it correctly. From the docs page, [PtVisible()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-ptvisible) "determines whether the specified point is within the clipping region of a device context." This has nothing to do with mouse location or location of a pixel within a window. This has specific uses to check whether the point is within the clipping region of a graphics device context.

If you want to check whether the mouse is within a certain window, you might want to try checking if your mouse coordinate is within GetWindowRect(). And then to check whether or not any windows overlap, you'd want to EnumWindows() and then IntersectRect()